# Is there a keyboard shortcut for closing a file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Or better yet a key combo that both save and close an open file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Close an open file: ctrl+f4 (for c# environment settings)

Comment: Or, via context menu: `Alt`+`F`+`C`

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly a keyboard combo, but if you press Ctrl+s (save), then let go of the s and press F4 (close), it'll do what you want.

Otherwise, the [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) extension will do a standard save and close with ZZ.

Answer (score 6):

Shift + Esc

Find them all the shortcut keys [here](http://www.veodin.com/keyrocket/visual-studio-2012-shortcuts/) with search

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure out why my files got closed when I tried to save them and fat-fingered the VsVim key sequence `<Esc>:w<Enter>`.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to know all the Visual Studio shortcuts you could use, you will love this app: KeyRocket Premium for Visual Studio (http://bit.ly/WRalto). It suggests context-aware keyboard shortcuts while you work on the Microsoft app, so you don't have to look for them on the Internet and then write them down to remember.